# Printing Object Embedded PDFs with Multiple Pages

Tags: html, pdf, vbscript

I am creating a page that loops through a database, using VBScript, and displays both images and PDFs. When I go to print the page, it only prints the first page of a multi-page PDF. How can I get it to print all of the pages in the PDF and not just the first page?

I am using the object tag to display the PDFs.

```html
 <object data="../FileName" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```